# NotSerializableException after adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

So I have this class called World:

```
public class World implements Serializable {

    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Path path;
    public ImageIcon image;
    public ArrayList<Location> locations;
```

I was serializing and deserializing it just fine before I added an object to the `ArrayList<Location> locations;`

Now when I try to run the serialization

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Main.board.worldpath.toString());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(Main.board.world.image);
    oos.writeObject(Main.board.world);
    oos.close();
}catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

It throws `java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath` in this line `oos.writeObject(Main.board.world);`

The class Location is also serializable:

```
public class Location implements Serializable {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public String name;
    public String desc;
```

I'm not sure why it would say that it's not serializable so is there anything special about serializing ArrayLists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the "Path". The Class is not Serializable. 
You can save "path" as string for example and create a new path on load.

Implement readObject and writeObject for it and make the path transient.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to a String and it works now. Odd, I've been loading and saving these worlds with the Path there but it never threw me an exception.

Comment: Perhaps it has always been `null` up until now.